# find most frequent subset in dataframe

Tags: r, combinations, overlap

So I have the following dataframe:

and what I want is to find the combination of genes that are present together the most.

```
  sample genea geneb genec gened genee genef
1      1     1     1     1     0     0     0
2      2     1     1     1     0     0     0
3      3     1     0     0     1     1     1
4      4     0     0     0     0     0     0
5      5     1     0     1     1     1     1
6      6     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

so in this case, my desired output would be:
gene a + c = 3 samples overlap.

`test[sort.list(colSums(test[,-1]), decreasing=TRUE)[1:15] +1])` gives me a list with most 1 values per gene. But I am getting stuck with this.

How do I approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `crossprod()`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  pivot_longer(-sample) %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  table() %>%
  crossprod() %>%
  replace(lower.tri(., diag = TRUE), NA) %>%
  as.data.frame.table() %>%
  slice_max(Freq)

   name name.1 Freq
1 genea  genec    3
```

Comment: would this also be possible to find more then 2 genes? My dataset is a lot bigger than the example I gave. For me it would be interesting also if there is a high frequency of, for instance 3 or 4 genes

Comment: No, this solution is limited to pairs only.  The solution that Ric posted can be expanded to sets of arbitrary size though.

Comment: for this solution it says my dataframe is too large. O well, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

Might not be suitable for every case, but here's a start:

```r
comb <- combn(colnames(df[-1]), m = 2)
overlap <- sapply(1:ncol(comb), \(i) sum(rowSums(df[comb[, i]]) == 2))

list(max.overlap = max(overlap),
     wm = df[comb[, which.max(overlap)]])

# $max.overlap
# [1] 3
# 
# $wm
#   genea genec
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     1
# 3     1     0
# 4     0     0
# 5     1     1
# 6     0     0
```

Comment: Hey @Mael, thanks for the reaction. I will see what I can do with this!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to visualize intersections, you could use `ComplexUpset` package :

```
library(ComplexUpset)
ComplexUpset::upset(test[,-1],colnames(test[,-1]))
```

But it might not be useful if you apply it to a lot of genes.

[image]

Comment: I will give it a try, its 3000 genes x)

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```r
test <- data.frame(sample = 1:6, 
                   genea = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
                   geneb = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                   genec = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
                   gened = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
                   genee = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
                   genef = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L))
```

Counting the matches:

```
data.frame(
  count = colSums(combn(subset(test,, -sample), 2, rowSums) == 2),
  gene = t(combn(subset(test,, -sample), 2, colnames ))) 

#>    count gene.1 gene.2
#> 1      2  genea  geneb
#> 2      3  genea  genec
#> 3      2  genea  gened
#> 4      2  genea  genee
#> 5      2  genea  genef
#> 6      2  geneb  genec
#> 7      0  geneb  gened
#> 8      0  geneb  genee
#> 9      0  geneb  genef
#> 10     1  genec  gened
#> 11     1  genec  genee
#> 12     1  genec  genef
#> 13     2  gened  genee
#> 14     2  gened  genef
#> 15     2  genee  genef
```

Filtering those with the most matches

```
subset(
  data.frame(
    count = colSums(combn(subset(test,, -sample), 2, rowSums) == 2),
    gene = t(combn(subset(test,, -sample), 2, colnames ))), 
  count == max(count))

#>   count gene.1 gene.2
#> 2     3  genea  genec
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>